# Project points to a vector layer and get z elevation at QGIS

Tags: qgis, elevation

I have one point file and one dtm vector file (with elevation contours as well as point elevation information).

How can I project points to the vector file and get z elevation of them?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to

1. create a raster DEM from your vector data: [Creating DEM from contours in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18116/is-it-possible-to-make-a-dem-from-contours-in-qgis/18117#18117) and then
2. [Extracting raster values at points using Open Source GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/extract-raster-values-at-points)

Comment: thanks for your respond. I have another question, actually I have dxf file of contour line. what is your advice to get z value of points. thanks

Comment: dxf files should load like any other vector layer. what issue do you have?

Comment: thanks for you respond, actually I import dxf files also I convert them to shp file. but I have another vector point layer that those don't have z elevation and I am going to make a surface(or Tin or any other thing) to can get z elevation of points. Thanks in advance