# How do I add elevation data to my layer

Tags: qgis, elevation, terrain-tools

I have a layer showing elevation curves and I'm trying to create an elevation profile using the Terrain Profile plugin. However, I only get a flat line. My guess is that I need to add Z values to the curves. The layer attribute table does have a column with height values(hoyde). [image]

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Profile Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/) you are using says that it:

> plots profile lines from raster layers or point vector layer with elevation field

This means that it won't work on contours which is what you have. 
Two options are:

- To get a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) from your contours by following the steps described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18116/creating-dem-from-contours-in-qgis).

or

- Convert the contours to points. This could be done with the 'Points along Geometry' tool, described [here](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-points-along-line).

Terrain data can be confusing on first acquaintance as there are lots of ways of representing it. There is a general tutorial [here](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_terrain.html).

Comment: You may also be able to download a DEM for your area of interest. If available, it will be more accurate than converting the contours to a DEM, since the contours were probably created from a DEM in the first place, and you lose some information every time you do a conversion.