# Create an interactive elevation map starting from GPX files in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, elevation, gpx

I just went on a trip and have GPX files of my hikes. Along with that I have "tracks" (without elevation data) and "track points" located on the same route but with elevation data.

- Tracks file: polyline without elevation details
  [image]
- Track_points file: point with elevation data along the track (field ele)
  [image]

I would like to represent the elevation profiles of my hikes, in addition to the hike routes themselves on an interactive map in ArcGIS Online so I can share the link with others.

Which is the best way to represent this in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Your question is too broad and will be closed by the moderators.  The elevation values from the GPX will be in heights above the WGS84 ellipsoid and not above 'sea level' which is what you are likely wanting.  If you have a surface (in some geoid heights) you can populate your data with those values and map from there.  For example https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-surface-information.htm.  You mention AGOL but you show QGIS so start here for QGIS:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317534/how-do-i-add-elevation-data-to-my-layer

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in ArcGIS Online, you can create an Experience using Experience Builder, and use the [Elevation Profile Widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/latest/configure-widgets/elevation-profile-widget.htm).  The widget can be configured to let users select the track (polyline) on the map and draw the elevation profile for you.

In my screenshot, I simply create a line without storing z-data or elevation data.  The profile is created from Esri's default elevation service.  Once you create the application, you can share it to whomever.

[image: profile_screenshot]