# Clean DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, contour, rasterization

I'm attempting to create a DEM in QGIS from contours using the "[Rasterize (vector to raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster)" function.

How do I create a DEM that is clean and does not have blank spots?

[image: DEM]

[image: contours]

[image: settings]

Comment: I would use a simple filtering tool, for instance, a median filter with a tiny smoothing value (or find the best threshold?)

Answer (score 2):

The rasterize tool is only making a raster version of your line data.  Each 300 ft x 300 ft pixel is picking up a value of one of the contour lines that would overlap that pixel.  This is the wrong choice for making a surface model.

Use one of the interpolation tools.  [Descriptions for using these tools are available here.](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html)

Or see this question: [Creating DEM from contours in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18116/creating-dem-from-contours-in-qgis)