# How to obtain elevation points for a road using contour?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst

I have contour lines, & roads centerlines feature classes, I need to get points with elevation in the starts, intersections, & the ends of the roads, how can I get this information? I used the "Intersect" approximity analysis tool, but I think it is not accurate enough. is there a way in 3D analyst or Spatial analyst? 
Thanks

In the case that roads overlap each other on different elevation, is there better way to still find the elevation for each street centerline segment (from node, and to node)? I have both contour line and DEM for the area. But the roads overlap a lot.

Comment: So, you are trying to interpolate contour lines to estimate elevation at different spots along your road lines? You don't have access to any DEM data in your area of interest?

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to skin the cat, but I don't know if you want ArcGIS (what extensions do you have?) or an Open Source solution.

For ArcGIS, one way is to create a [DEM from your contours](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10678/creating-a-dem-from-contours), and [assign Zs to the vertexes](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1734&t=295499).