# Creating DEM from contours without ArcGIS Spatial Analyst licence

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, contour

I'm trying to create a 3d DEM/DTM from a flat contour shapefile which has height data attached to each contour, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I've found [Creating DEM from contours using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10678), on creating a dem from contours using the Topo to Raster tool, (using the ANUDEM technology,) which looks great but I don't have a Spatial Analyst licence, so is there another way to do this, using a standard ArcView/Basic level licence (version 9.2)?

I'm currently investigating QGIS as an alternative, via the process at [Generating DEM from contour Shapefile using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60228) though I've only just downloaded QGIS, so while I'm new to GIS I am SLIGHTLY more familiar with ArcMap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely out of luck with ArcGIS without (Spatial Analyst or 3D Analyst licenses)
Licensing for ArcGIS can range from a few extra dollars to many thousands.

For Creating DEM using QGIS use the GRASS tools - more info is available from [Generating DEM from contour Shapefile using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60228)