# Create Contours From a DEM without 3D or Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, contour

I'm wondering if there is a way to create contours from a DEM using ArcGIS without 3D or Spatial Analyst Extensions.

I know that there are a few questions out there pertaining to this ([How to create DEM from contours without ArcGIS Spatial Analyst licence?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78210/how-to-create-dem-from-contours-without-arcgis-spatial-analyst-licence)), but I'd like to specifically ask if there is a workaround for this. Like I said this is more of a curiosity type question. My organization is looking to cut budget and I personally would like to cut down on some of the ArcGIS licensing cost. Major projects that we do here are elevation related and we need this functionality. Like I said, QGIS can complete it, but some clients request the work be done in ArcGIS.

Currently I'm trying a mix of DEM to points to contours, but with no luck so far. Crunching a DEM to points is a long resource trying task so it's not optimal, but I think it may work. But after that I really need to find a way to go from point to contour. Is there a free ArcGIS add-in with a functionality like this?

Comment: Although not among the free functions, [ET Geowizards and ET Surface](http://www.ian-ko.com/) both have functions for creating contours. Probably still a lot cheaper than buying SA or 3DA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find contour tools in [GME](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmecommands.htm) or [ETgeowizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/).

If you want to create contour from points, you could try reclassify your points into some height categories, then use dissolved buffer, but this will create artefacts. A proper way is to use Thiessen polygons, but this will require huge processing (and you'll need advanced licence).

Comment: ETgeowizard to the rescue again. You Shall Not Pass ESRI.

Answer (score 2):

For the contouring there are several open source solutions like [CONREC](http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/) from Paul Bourke, [OPENCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) has also a proper contouring algorithms and [my](http://www.triplexware.huckfinn.de/contweber.html) stuff is also available. The more complex stuff, to build the regular mesh from a irregular point set can be done by triangulation and resampling with [triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) or [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/).