# Client-side 3D surface generation in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, 3d, topography, surface, mesh

Is there any way to create some sort of 3D surface (mesh, TIN, elevationLayer) from contour lines on the client side with ArcGIS JS API? Or alternatively edit a hosted 3D surface (any format)? In our application, the user can draw/edit contour lines, so I was wondering if there is way to generate a 3D surface from those edited contour lines on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom elevation layer by subclassing [BaseElevationLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-BaseElevationLayer.html). More details are [here](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit17/papers/dev_int_97.pdf#page=13).

Hope this helps.

Richie.

Comment: I used BaseElevationLayer, and was able to modify it (basically to do cut and fill on topography). But the resolution (pixel size) doesn't seem to be adequate for detailed 3D modeling. I was trying to put a building on a very steep land and get a rough estimate of the volume of needed cut and fill under the building. But the edges don't perfectly align with building footprint, given the relatively large size of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Topo to Raster is a geoprocessing tool that relies on the Spatial Analyst extension in ArcGIS Desktop and could theoretically be published as a custom GP service in ArcGIS Enterprise and consumed from a JSAPI application.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-topo-to-raster-works.htm

related: [Creating a dem from contours](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10678/creating-a-dem-from-contours)

Comment: Although I don't have ArcGIS Enterprise license for project I am currently working on, this is definitely something to consider for future projects.